# How to use stored properties in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm new to Objective-C and i'm coming from Swift where i can declare a view as so

```
var container_view: UIView = {
    var v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .white
    return v
}()
```

but here in objective-c is there anyway i can implement this in my header file or .m file here is what have tried

```
-(UILabel *) laf {
   UILabel *u = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   u.text = @"Label here";
   u.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   return u;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Swift property is a stored property with an initial value that is calculated once.

Objective-C has no such feature. Though you can simulate it with the proper code.

First you need to declare the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *containerView;
```

Put that in the .h if it's public. Put that in the class extension if it's private.

To provide a (lazy) default value, you need to override the getter method:

```
- (UIView *)containerView {
    if (_containerView == nil) {
        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _containerView = v
    }

    return _containerView
}
```

It would be best to use `dispatch_once` instead of the `if` if there is any chance this property will be accessed from more than just the main queue.